# Oracle SQL - Left join on "in" statements

Tags: sql, oracle

The point of the query below is to return a list of people and whether or not they are unhappy. But, If I don't know if they are happy or not, I want to list their name and their unhappy as "happy". This is complicated by the fact that I have some additional requirements for what defines unhappy.

I'm writing a query like this...

```
Select name.firstName,
     CASE
       WHEN Mood.mood is not null
       THEN 'Unhappy'
       ELSE 'Happy'
     END Unhappy
From name
     Mood
WHERE mood.firstName(+) = name.firstName
AND mood.type        IN ('Hungry','Tired','Fatigued','Bored',null)
AND mood.value(+)    > 5;
```

So I want to return every single name from the table name, and either a value of "happy" or "unhappy", even though those names may or may not be in mood table. When I run this as I've written it, I get no rows. I figure this might involve my mood.type line because I can't use a left join on an "in" statement.

Comment: Did you try to comment the mood.type condition and see if you get any rows? Just to make sure that the rest of the conditions are correct.

Comment: Good thought. I will check that next if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have a couple of problems:

1. You have a spurious semi-colon in your WHERE clause.
2. The CASE expression is in the wrong place.
3. You shouldn't use NULL in an IN expression.

You could remove the semi-colon and change your IN expression to this instead:

```
AND (mood.type IN ('Hungry','Tired','Fatigued','Bored') OR mood.type IS NULL)
```

Also, I'd strongly advise you not to use that obsolete join syntax. It's probably a good idea to use the JOIN keyword as it makes this sort of query a lot easier.

```
SELECT
    name.firstName,
    CASE
       WHEN Mood.mood IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'Unhappy'
       ELSE 'Happy'
    END Unhappy
FROM name
LEFT JOIN Mood ON
    mood.firstName = name.firstName AND
    mood.type IN ('Hungry','Tired','Fatigued','Bored') AND
    mood.value > 5
```

Comment: Running query now to see if this works. But as for the other snytax, geez, that's brilliant! You can group all of the left join stuff. I am a little confused about the syntax. What if I'd written, for example, RIGHT JOIN Mood on (the rest of that stuff)?

Comment: @Mark:  The `CASE` seems misplaced, too.

Comment: @Mark You're absolutely right. In my actual query I have it in the right place (i.e. the select statement). I'll move it in my question.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks. Problem count is now at three. :)

Comment: Hey, I'm now returning rows. It looks like it was as simple as moving the (null) out of the in and into a seperate clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
select n.firstname,
    nvl(m.mood, 'Happy') mood
from
    name n
    left outer join mood m
        on n.firstname = m.firstname
where
    nvl(m.type,'Hungry') in ('Hungry', 'Tired', 'Fatigued', 'Bored')
```